# How can i merge binary excel cell created by C#?

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

i use this code to create  one cell of excel via C#.

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the text cell value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="row">The row.</param>
/// <param name="col">The col.</param>
/// <param name="value">The string value.</param>
public void WriteCell(int row, int col, string value)
{
  ushort[] clData = { 0x0204, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  int iLen = value.Length;
  byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
  clData[1] = (ushort)(8 + iLen);
  clData[2] = (ushort)row;
  clData[3] = (ushort)col;
  clData[5] = (ushort)iLen;
  WriteUshortArray(clData);
  writer.Write(plainText);
}
```

What changes is needed to add merged cell?

Comment: Post the complete code... `WriteUshortArray`?

Comment: See this simple  Tutorial http://forum.codecall.net/topic/71705-c-tutorial-writing-binary-excel-files/

Comment: I use this code. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33850/Generate-Excel-files-without-using-Microsoft-Excel

Comment: Dear Ramesh Rajendran, my project is silverlight and i can not use 'microsoft.office.interop.excel' in client machin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a video from Microsoft [How Do I: Create Excel Spreadsheets using LINQ to XML?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb927708.aspx)

There are other methods beside writing excel files in the proprietary format, such as: http://epplus.codeplex.com/?

I wouldn't suggest using the Microsoft Excel BIFF format.